# Repeat cURL command once a minute using a list in a table

Tags: unix, curl

Not entirely sure if what I'm asking is possible but thought i'd see;

I'm using the cURL command to access an API, this site allows a maximum search of 1 per minute otherwise there is a 'Too Many Requests' error.

Basically I'm repeating the following manually for example;

```
     curl http://example.org/<query ID>.tsv > <filename>.tsv
```

Where the query ID is an ID from a database, is there any way to automate this to do the following command, but change the query ID and output filename every time. The database is accessible by a URL, or I can download it into a tsv file. Can I access each row of a specific column, but searching only once per minute?

The database is; https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=taxonomy%3A%22Escherichia+coli+O127%3AH6+%28strain+E2348%2F69+%2F+EPEC%29+%5B574521%5D%22&sort=score where the query ID corresponds to each value in the entry name column.

Thanks!

Comment: Such a thing is certainly possible, so search here for `[bash] loop curl` and see what you find. You have some fun learning ahead of you. Any further questions should include small set of sample input, required output from the same sample input, your code, current output, error messages and your questions or concerns about why it's not working. It will probably be easier to have a separate process that generates the list of "each value in the entry name column" , save that as a file, and then use a loop with a `sleep 61` command to call curl with the correct URL and output file. Good luck.

Comment: And as you have experience with Python, I'd recommend searching for here for similar terms, but with `[python]` instead of `[bash]`. Extracting the ~4000 values will be the hard part. As this is really a `[web-scrapping]` problem, you'll want to learn about `[beautifulsoup]` and similar tools. Generally, these sort of projects can take a lot of time. You might luck out and find that an on-line automated tool like `import.io` can get the column data you want, but that will take experiment time too (and may not give you direct results). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the suggestions, and apologies about the formatting it's been a while since I've used these forums. I've created a list of the entry names, and from what i've read I can use `while read` and then direct to my curl function and then sleep but haven't got it down perfect yet and not sure if I need to assign each to a function first. Thanks again!